# Can MacBook Air 2017 handle 4k video playback

Tags: macos, performance, hdmi, displayport, 4k

I bought a 4k monitor and now I am connecting the monitor to my MacBook Air 2017 with the mini-DisplayPort to HDMI cable. This cable supports 1440p on 59.98 FPS, or 4K on 30 FPS.

When it is on 1440p, I can play 4K video on VLC without a problem, but on 4K 30fps, the 4K videos are lagging a lot. **Is it possible that the problem is with the 30fps and if I buy a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable to be able to get 60fps output on 4K the problem would be solved?** The CPU of this model is 5th generation (intel Core i5 5350u) and I've heard that it does not have HEVC acceleration and that might cause a problem.

Currently on 4K even with scaling from 1440p and HiDPI with BetterDisplay I do not have any problem other than lagging on 4K video playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always recommend ditching HDMI and using DisplayPort for performance and reliability reasons. You should expect full 60 Hz at 4k resolution as that’s the spec and Apple is generally conservative in that it lists officially in that you get more performance typically than the reported values.

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz on an external display, both at millions of colors.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753?locale=en_US

Unless you have other CPU or cooling or encoding issues, you seem close to a good setup and only need a quality DP cable. You can buy extra GPU for the external display by closing the clamshell and letting the internal display be free from rendering. But as above, both should refresh full speed and full color simultaneously.